# How to print a large map easily from QGIS where I can later zoom in on minute details?

Tags: print-composer, zoom

I have a cadastral map with more than 20000 plots. For a ground survey, we need to use this map to capture details of each plot.

I want to make a pdf file that can opened on mobile phones for the survey. Here is how the map should look like

Actual map on map canvas
[image: Actual map on map canvas]

This is how the zoomed in version should look like.

[image: Zoomed in map]

This is how much zoomed in level I require. I want it to zoom in in the pdf just like it zooms in on the qgis desktop

But, unfortunately, I need to zoom in on each map tile and cut it, merge in paint and export as pdf. Otherwise, 90% of details are lost by printing it via the print composer. This is an extremely painstaking procedure and I wonder if there is an easier way.

I tried to load it as extremely high res map on print composer and exported as pdf, still the details are missing.

Is there a possibility to print the entire map outside of the map canvas? Then I can zoom the map to the level I want and print the entire map? This process takes me somewhere close to 10 hours and it is precious time lost.

Comment: I don't understand "90% of details are lost by printing it via the print composer". What do you mean by "details"? You've just got polygons and labels. 90% of the polygons not showing?

Comment: A PDF is (usually) a fixed representation of a paper page. Making a PDF map that looks good at more than one zoom level is probably impossible. If you specify very small label sizes (unreadable at full zoom) and make sure they are in page units you should get something that looks okay when viewed zoomed in, but tiny when zoomed out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me you need a webmap, not a print. If I were you I would generate a webmap with QGIS Cloud (super easy) or the qgis2web plugin in 10 minutes.

Comment: I made the web map. How do we export that so that it can be viewed on a mobile phone?

Comment: Excellent! If QGIS Cloud is already online just hit the mobile url in the phones browser. I doubt a offline solution is available. If qgis2web you already exported the files, see the settings when generating the webmap. Normally you would put the exported files on a webserver (like a homepage) and visit it with a browser. It guess its possible to put these files on a phone and open the html but how depends on brand phone. Personally I wouldn't go through that trouble when using a smartphone because it should have mobile internet.